# Pivot table DataBodyRange.Count issues

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am working on a VBA form that manipulates and pulls from a pivot table.

I can watch as the filters are applied through my code and see the pivot table update accordingly.

Then I loop through the DataBodyRange from 1 to DataBodyRange.Count and "do" stuff with each row.

It worked great till I found out through some watches and breakpoints that when the DataBodyRange has a single item (plus the "Header") count is 1

But also, if the DataBodyRange has 0 items (in other words ONLY the "header" row) count STILL returns 1

---

I can demonstrate the behavior. Take the following table and its corresponding PivotTable:

[image]

Report Layout is Tabular

Using the following Test sub

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim PT As PivotTable
  Dim PF As PivotField
  Dim F As PivotFilter

  Set PT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
  Set PF = PT.PivotFields("Name")
  Set F = PF.PivotFilters(1)
  MsgBox "Filter: """ & F.Value1 & _
         """ As Filter Type " & F.FilterType & _
         " on PivotField """ & PF.Name & _
         """ DataBodyRange.Count = " & PT.DataBodyRange.Count
End Sub
```

Applying first filter for control test

[image]

Corresponding PivotTable change

[image]

Running Test():

[image]

Returns 1 as expected

---

Now that the control is established

Let's apply a filter that does NOT match anything

[image]

and PivotTable Changes

[image]

And finally running Test()

[image]

---

The VBA code I'm actually working with at work is Excel 2010. These screen shots are from Excel 2013 so this "behavior" seems to be pretty consistent across versions.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's very hard to give suggestion without seeing your PT (atleast screenshot).

Comment: Yeah I posted this on my phone as they only time i had to ask for help was as i was in transit (Walking not driving)

Also this behavior is consistent no matter what spreadsheet i make so it didn't seem like the kind of thing that NEEDS a code sample.

However I'm working on screen shots for a spreadsheet i set up at home (Question is about a work project) that replicates the same behavior.

Stay Tuned....

Comment: DataBodyRange does not take into account applied filters.
If you look up a col or row 'index' with yourpivottable.RowRange or .ColumnRange, those numbers do not reflect the intersection, when some filters are set. Absolutely annoying and bad code, imho.